# Alert on with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a table on my JSP file that show my products and on every row I have a button that delete this data:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="product" items="${list}">
            <tr>
                <td>${product.id}</td>
                <td>${product.name}</td>
                <td>R$${product.value}</td>
                <td>${product.quantity}</td>
                <td>R$${product.quantity * product.value}</td>
                <td><a href="showProduct?id=${product.id}">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="deleteProduct?id=${product.id}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <br><br>
    <a href="newProduct">New product</a>
</body>
```

I wish to create an alert when I click on Delete button.

I know that I have to use javascript, but, how can I after click on "Ok" redirect to my controller deleteProduct ?

I tried something like this:

```
<script>
if (confirm('Do you really want to delet this product?')) {
    ???
} else {
    alert('The product was not deleted');
}
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

```js
function confirmDelete(aProductID){
if (confirm('Do you really want to delet this product?')) {
    document.location.href='deleteProduct?id='+aProductID;
} else {
    alert('The product was not deleted');
}
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="product" items="${list}">
            <tr>
                <td>${product.id}</td>
                <td>${product.name}</td>
                <td>R$${product.value}</td>
                <td>${product.quantity}</td>
                <td>R$${product.quantity * product.value}</td>
                <td><a href="showProduct?id=${product.id}">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="#1" onclick="confirmDelete(${product.id})">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <br><br>
    <a href="newProduct">New product</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<td><a href="deleteProduct?id=${product.id}" onclick="return deleteProduct()">Delete</a></td>


<script>
function deleteProduct()
{
    if (confirm('Do you really want to delet this product?')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('The product was not deleted');
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

If you `return true` in the `onclick` method of an `<a>` tag it will go to the url `else` if you `return false` it won't...

Comment: Hi brso05, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately i tried this, but when i click both ok or cancel the product is deleted. I tried the solution below, submited by @Rene Lykke Dahl and it works, but i really really appreciate your reply, many thanks man :)

Comment: @RaphaelTelatim ya that was my bad...I updated the answer it should work now.